# Using variables to create SQL parameters

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a loop that takes values from textboxes and dropdowns and uses them to update a an SQL table.  I need to be able to rename the parameters and give them values based on the variable that the loop counts to.  Example: if loop goes from 0 to 2 then textname_0 will go to @paramname_0 and textname_1 goes to @paramname_1 and so on.

I have written the code below but it generates an error which intimates the first parameter can't be found so the syntax is clearly wrong.

```
    Protected Sub Insert_To_Tables()

    Try


        Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection()
        Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=wolf;Initial Catalog=Seat_Planner_2013;Integrated Security=True;Integrated Security=True"
        Using cn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)

            For i As Int32 = 0 To number_of_tickets_Ddl.SelectedValue

                cn.Open()
                Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tables ([table_num], [seat], [available], [ticket_num], [seat_title], [seat_firstname], [seat_surname], [booking_ref],[booked_by]) VALUES (@table_num_ & i, @seat_ & i, @available_ & i, @ticket_num_ & i, @seat_title_ & i, @seat_firstname_ & i, @seat_surname_ & i, @booking_ref, @booked_by) WHERE ([table_num] = @table_num) AND ([seat] = @seat_ & i)"

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@table_num", SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = ddltable.SelectedValue
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@seat_" & i, SqlDbType.NChar).Value = CType(Me.FindControl(("DDLSeat_") & i), DropDownList).SelectedValue
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@available", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = "No"
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ticket_num_" & i, SqlDbType.NChar).Value = CType(Me.FindControl(("TicketNo_TextBox_") & i), TextBox).Text.Trim
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@seat_title_" & i, SqlDbType.NChar).Value = CType(Me.FindControl(("Title_TextBox_") & i), TextBox).Text.Trim
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@seat_firstname_" & i, SqlDbType.NChar).Value = CType(Me.FindControl(("FirstName_TextBox_") & i), TextBox).Text.Trim
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@seat_surname_" & i, SqlDbType.NChar).Value = CType(Me.FindControl(("Surname_TextBox_") & i), TextBox).Text.Trim
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@booking_ref", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = booking_ref_LBL.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@booked_by", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = CType(Me.FindControl(("TBoxFull_name_0")), TextBox).Text.Trim

                cmd.Connection = cn
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                cn.Close()

            Next

        End Using

        DB_error1.Text = " Insert to tables success. "

    Catch ex As Exception

        DB_error1.Text = "Fail "
        DB_error1.Text = DB_error1.Text + ex.Message.ToString
    Finally

    End Try
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL doesn't have dynamic parameters names - they are fixed. For example - you have a `@table_num` parameter in the SQL query (`CommandText`). Additionally, you have `& i` **inside the string**, making this **invalid SQL**.

Just use `(@table_num, @seat, @available,  ...`

The added parameters **must match** these names, so concatenating is the *wrong* thing to do either in the SQL or when adding the parameters.

Just drop the concatenation and things should work as you expect.

---

For efficiency, I suggest you read up on [table valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx).

Comment: OK I think I may have been barking up the wrong tree, forgetting that the loop would create and 'overwrite' the parameters anyway.  I have made the change and the parameters are now recognised. I have marked yours as the answer. Thanks.  The where clause is throwing an error though, how should the update line look?

Comment: @Ryan - You have not given detail of the error, so I can't really help. Check for concatenations again.

Comment: Sorry, I have removed the concatenation and that all makes sense now, it just seems like a basic syntax error (Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'). I guessed what the line should look like at this point, this is clearly not right: WHERE [table_num] = @table_num AND [seat] = @sea)

Comment: @Ryan - Well, you can't use `WHERE` on an `INSERT`. That would be it (what would be the point?).

Comment: Well that was embarrassing, of course that was supposed to be an UPDATE command not INSERT.  Everything is now working, thanks for pointing out my (now) abvious mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your `cmd.CommandText`, You should take the variable `i` to out of quotes.
2. You also set the parameter name to `@table_num` but you are tying to use it like `@table_num_1`

   cmd.Parameters.Add(**"@table_num"**, SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = ddltable.SelectedValue

   cmd.CommandText = ...VALUES (**@table_num_ & i**, ...

   Same with the `@available` parameter

You see the parameter names will not be same, so when you fix this two issues, other parts seem OK.